# Count number of POS in (word,pos) tuples of NLTK tagged sentences

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, nltk, counter, pos-tagger

I have a list of tuples and I'm trying to count number of keys of tuples. The following is my code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import treebank
from collections import Counter

# print treebank.fileids()
treebank_raw = list(treebank.tagged_sents()) ##treebank_raw is a list of list (of tuples)                        

treebank_flipped = []
treebank_flipped_counter = Counter()
for sent in treebank_raw:
    flipped = {b : a.lower() for a, b in sent}
    treebank_flipped_counter.update(flipped.items())
```

If I were to count number of u'VBD', `print treebank_flipped_count` reveals the following to be all independent cases when in fact I want to count them together.

```
(u'VBD', u'said'): 405
(u'VBD', u'was'): 264
(u'VBD', u'were'): 138
```

So that u'VBD' : (405 + 264 + 138). How do I dissolve keys of tuples and count them altogether?

Answer (score 1):

You can skip most of the code for this.
All you need is:

```
from nltk.corpus import treebank
from collections import Counter

pos_counts = Counter(pos for _, pos in treebank.tagged_sents())
```

The variable `pos_counts` will count how many times each part-of-speech tag occurs with any word token.

(The `_` part in the generator expression simply means that we are not interested in the word token. You could just as well write `pos for token, pos in ...`, but it's  a convention in Python to use `_` for throw-away values.)

Answer (score 0):

@lenz answer on using the Counter and list comprehension is good.

But if you need something a little more complicated, esp. when you need to also retrieve the word+pos counts other than the the pos / word counts, maybe this would help:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
corpus_counts = defaultdict(Counter)
for word, pos in treebank.tagged_sents():
    corpus_counts[pos][word] +=1
```

[out]:

```
>>> corpus_counts['NNPS']
Counter({u'Securities': 16, u'Containers': 16, u'Industries': 12, u'Materials': 10, u'Soviets': 8, u'Americans': 6, u'Associates': 5, u'Airlines': 5, u'Savings': 5, u'Motors': 5, u'States': 5, u'Democrats': 5, u'Systems': 4, u'Markets': 4, u'Resources': 4, u'Services': 4, u'Travelers': 4, u'Communications': 4, u'Stores': 3, u'Investors': 3, u'Partners': 3, u'Giants': 3, u'Machines': 3, u'Brothers': 3, u'Philippines': 3, u'Issues': 3, u'Friends': 3, u'Messrs.': 2, u'Laboratories': 2, u'Engineers': 2, u'Futures': 2, u'Burgundies': 2, u'Islands': 2, u'Options': 2, u'Cabernets': 2, u'Nations': 2, u'Instruments': 2, u'Writers': 2, u'Dealers': 2, u'Institutes': 2, u'ADRs': 2, u'Contras': 2, u'Lakes': 1, u'Tots': 1, u'BILLS': 1, u'Manufacturers': 1, u'Republicans': 1, u'Journals': 1, u'Netherlands': 1, u'Notes': 1, u'Products': 1, u'Underwoods': 1, u'Operations': 1, u'ASSETS': 1, u'Facilities': 1, u'Foods': 1, u'Preferences': 1, u'Holdings': 1, u'BRIEFS': 1, u'Dakotas': 1, u'Plains': 1, u'Toys': 1, u'Lawyers': 1, u'Utilities': 1, u'Monopolies': 1, u'Chardonnays': 1, u'Inns': 1, u'Charities': 1, u'Parkinson': 1, u'Fundamentalists': 1, u'Centers': 1, u'Bridges': 1, u'Yorkers': 1, u'SOYBEANS': 1, u'Pictures': 1, u'Rieslings': 1, u'F-series': 1, u'ASSOCIATES': 1, u'RATES': 1, u'Lawmakers': 1, u'Contracts': 1, u'Investments': 1, u'Dolphins': 1, u'Appropriations': 1, u'Mergers': 1, u'Productions': 1, u'Virginians': 1, u'Works': 1, u'Donuts': 1, u'Angels': 1, u'Asians': 1, u'GRAINS': 1, u'Airways': 1, u'Elders': 1, u'Delegates': 1, u'Germans': 1, u'Articles': 1, u'Lines': 1, u'METALS': 1, u'Publications': 1, u'Mercedes': 1, u'Craftsmen': 1, u'Builders': 1, u'Appeals': 1, u'Bricklayers': 1, u'FUNDS': 1, u'Springs': 1})

# Count of `Securities|NNPS`:
>>> corpus_counts['NNPS']['Securities']
16

# Count of all `NNPS`:
>>> sum(corpus_counts['NNPS'].values())
```